# C compile : collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, compilation, linker

I tried to search for that bug online, but all the posts are for C++.

This is the message:

```
test1.o: In function `ReadDictionary':
/home/johnny/Desktop/haggai/test1.c:13: undefined reference to `CreateDictionary'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test1] Error 1
```

It is super simple code, and I can't understand what the problem is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dict.h"
#include "hash.h"


pHash ReadDictionary() {
    /* This function reads a dictionary line by line from the standard input. */
    pHash dictionary;
    char entryLine[100] = "";
    char *word, *translation;

    dictionary = CreateDictionary();
    while (scanf("%s", entryLine) == 1) { // Not EOF
        word = strtok(entryLine, "=");
        translation = strtok(NULL, "=");
        AddTranslation(dictionary, word, translation);
    }
    return dictionary;
}

int main() {
    pHash dicti;
...
```

Now this is the header file *dict.h*:

```
#ifndef _DICT_H_
#define _DICT_H_

#include "hash.h"

pHash CreateDictionary();
...

#endif
```

And here is the *dict.c* file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hash.h"
#include "dict.h"


pHash CreateDectionary()
{
    pHash newDict;
    newDict = HashCreate(650, HashWord, PrintEntry, CompareWords, GetEntryKey, DestroyEntry);
    return newDict;
}
```

And if you want to check file hash.h:

```
#ifndef _HASH_H_
#define _HASH_H_

// Type definitions //
typedef enum {FAIL = 0, SUCCESS} Result;
typedef enum {SAME = 0, DIFFERENT} CompResult;

typedef struct _Hash Hash, *pHash;

typedef void* pElement;
typedef void* pKey;

// Function types //
typedef int (*HashFunc) (pKey key, int size);
typedef Result (*PrintFunc) (pElement element);
typedef CompResult (*CompareFunc) (pKey key1, pKey key2);
typedef pKey (*GetKeyFunc) (pElement element);
typedef void (*DestroyFunc)(pElement element);
...

// Interface functions //

#endif
```

Maybe it will be easier if I give you the files here?

Anyway, I will be happy for tips on how to understand the problem.

Comment: It's the same problem in C and C++, the linker can't find `CreateDictionary`. In your case, it's probably because you defined `CreateDectionary` instead ...

Comment: can you explain please? what i defined instead of what?

Comment: You have a typo. Dictionary not D**e**ctionary.

Comment: *"collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"* is a signature for [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) (GCC linker error).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your problem is the typo in the function CreateD**e**ctionary(). You should change it to CreateD**i**ctionary().

*collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status* is the same problem in both C and C++. Usually it means that you have unresolved symbols. In your case, it is the typo that I mentioned before.

Comment: Does the 'ld' in this indicate an error in the linker?

Comment: @UtahJarhead: No, not *in* the linker. A problem ***with*** *linking*. [ld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29#GNU_linker) is the GNU linker.

Answer (score 5):

I got this problem, and tried many ways to solve it. Finally, it turned out that `make clean` and `make` again solved it. The reason is:

I got the source code together with object files compiled previously with an ***old*** GCC version. When my newer GCC version wants to link that old object files, it can't resolve some function in there. It happens to me several times that the source code distributors do not clean up before packing, so a `make clean` saved the day.

Comment: Thank you! Just upgraded my computer and installed all my packages and just needed to this is last step 'make clean'

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this error came because it failed to compile in the middle of any build.

The best way to try is by doing *make clean* and again *make* the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling your program, you need to include dict.c as well, eg:

`gcc -o test1 test1.c dict.c`

Plus you have a typo in dict.c definition of `CreateDictionary`, it says `CreateDectionary` (`e` instead of `i`)

Comment: i did, still same problem

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g test1.c dict.c -o test1`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this problem occurred when we had called a function which had not been defined in the program file.

To sort out this problem, check whether you have called such a function which has not been defined in the program file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears when you have a running console at the time you try to run another (or the same) program.

I had this problem during executing a program in [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) while I had another one running in [Dev-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) already.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, and the solutions mentioned here helped me try out different things, but the root cause was that I missed the linking `.cpp` file in my `CMakeList.txt` file.

Answer (score -1):

Install this:

```
sudo apt install libgl-dev libglu-dev libglib2.0-dev libsm-dev libxrender-dev libfontconfig1-dev libxext-dev
```

*[collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/69625-collect2-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status)* (Qt Centre)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Qt, so this answer is completely irrelevant. Just because the person in that thread needed some of these libs to compile doesn't mean everyone getting a link error needs the same libs.

Comment: Totally agree with @Evan

Answer (score -2):

If you are using [Dev C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) then your `.exe` or mean to say your program already running and you are trying to run it again.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to say? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54302014/edit) (change) your answer. And/or explain here in comments.

Comment: It may or may not make more sense by reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593029/c-compile-collect2-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status/66202722#66202722).

Comment: OK, the OP may never return: *"Last seen more than a month ago"*