# "Old-style parameter declarations" error

Tags: c

I'm having two compile errors when trying to compile my code, and I can't find what the issue really is. Could anybody help shed some light?

```
error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition
error: 'i' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Code:

```
void printRecords (STUREC records[], int count)

STUREC records[ARRAY_MAX];
int count;
int i;
{
    printf("+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+\n");
    printf("| Student Name | ID | Test 1 | Test 2 | Proj 1 | Proj 2 | Proj 3 | Average | Grade |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+\n");

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        size_t j;
        printf ("|%s|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%f|%c|", records[i].name, records[i].id, records[i].score1,
                 records[i].score2, records[i].score3, records[i].score4, records[i].score5,
                  records[i].ave, records[i].grade);
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: looks like you misplaced the `{` bracket at the printRecords function definition ..

Comment: The opening `{` should follow the function parameter list.

Comment: ah! thank you guys... now i'm getting an error saying that in my function 'printRecords' 'count' is redeclared as a different kind of sybole with a note stating where my previous definition is. but i have `void printRecord (STUREC records[], int count)` followed by a local declaration of `int count;`... those are the two lines the error code is point at, but i have them both at int, so what could the error be referring to?

Answer (score 22):

Not for this specific question, but if you happen to come across this error, check that you did not miss a semicolon at the end of your declaration, because that's what happened to me.

Comment: saved me a lot of time, didn't add a semicolon at the end of my function protoype.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use [old style C parameter declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585390/c-function-syntax-parameter-types-declared-after-parameter-list), you need to do this:

```
void printRecords(records, count)
    STUREC records[ARRAY_MAX];
    int count;
{
    int i;
    // ... rest of the code ...
}
```

But this is not considered a good practice and can make your code harder to read. Some compilers have even stopped supporting this syntax.

The other comments/answers are saying that you *re-declare* (and therefore hide) your function parameters in the body of the function, but this is not what you want to do (otherwise you effectively lose the parameters being passed in).

If you define a function like this:

```
void fxn(int num) {
    int num;
    num = num;
}
```

What does `num` refer to: the parameter or the local variable?

Either do this:

```
void printRecords(records, count)
    STUREC records[ARRAY_MAX];
    int count;
{
    int i;
    // ... rest of the code ...
}
```

or do this:

```
void printRecords(STUREC records[], int count)
{
    int i;
    // ... rest of the code ...
}
```

But don't try to do both or a mixture of the two.

Comment: yeah, i just moved my { up haha and it took care of it. im now having an error saying my count in printRecords is being redeclared as a different symbol... the error points to lines 98 and 94. any clue?

Comment: @seanncurtis Get rid of the lines immediately after the `{` but before `int i;`. See the last example in my answer.

Comment: oh i see, if you declare count is an int in the () starting the function, you don't need to declare that in local declarations?

Comment: Bingo! Otherwise, the function doesn't know which one you are talking about.

Comment: makes perfect sense, thank you. i am now receiving an error i've never seen in the 4 months i've been learning c. it says 'error: 1d returned exit status'... it doesnt refer to a line or anything though.

Comment: That is a linker error and is completely different than your question here. There are a lot of answers about `ld returned exit status 1` on SO and online.

Comment: @seanncurtis If you think my answer helped, please upvote so that future users can apply this if they are encountering the same problem.

Comment: @seanncurtis [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593029/c-compile-collect2-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status) explains more about linker errors.

Comment: @callyalater What compilers have stopped supporting this syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
void printRecords (STUREC records[], int count)

STUREC records[ARRAY_MAX];
int count;
int i;
{
```

But I guess you want:

```
void printRecords (STUREC records[], int count)
{
    int i;
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to callyalater for noting the redeclaration of the parameters in the function...

Comment: Also, `i` is not a parameter in `printRecords` and the old style function parameters mean that you do not put the type in the function parameter declarations.

Comment: ah! thank you guys... now i'm getting an error saying that in my function 'printRecords' 'count' is redeclared as a different kind of sybole with a note stating where my previous definition is. but i have `void printRecord (STUREC records[], int count)` followed by a local declaration of `int count;`... those are the two lines the error code is point at, but i have them both at int, so what could the error be referring to?

Comment: @mame98 Your example doesn't do what you think it does. You re-declare the parameters as local variables which *hides* the parameters and makes them inaccessible for the rest of the function.