# C++: "error collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: c++, compilation

I am writing a simple program to calculate the derivative of a function, but I always get the error:

> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double derivative2(double (fun), double step, double x);
double fun(double);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    double h = atof(argv[1]);
    double x = sqrt(2);
    cout << derivative2(fun(x), h, x) << endl;
    return 0;
}


double derivative2(double fun(double), double step, double x) {
    return ((fun(x + step) - fun(x))/step);
}


double fun(double x) {
    return atan(x);
}
```

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27593029/2853667), but it is not useful in my case.

Comment: That error tends to follow at least one (possibly more) other error from the linker.   Those errors will usually be related to the cause of the problem.   In this case,  the problem is that the declaration of `derivative2()` immediately after the `using namespace std` does not match the definition, so you are overloading the function.   The call of `derivative2()` in `main()` calls the one that is not defined.   Since there is a call of a function that is not defined, the linker will typically report something like an "undefined reference".  The collect2 error follows from that.

Comment: @Peter Which is the correct definition? When they are equal I get a bunch of errors saying that *fun cannot be used as a function*.

Comment: The "correct definition" depends on what you're trying to achieve.  In terms of your code, the definition of `derivative2()` [which occurs after `main()`] is what you intend.   That function accepts a (pointer to) a function as the first argument.   However, the declaration of `derivative2()` after the `using namespace std` accepts a `double` as the first argument.   The usage of `derivative2()` in `main()` also passes a `double` (the result of calling `fun(x)`) to `derivative2()` - consistent with the preceding declaration of `derivative2()` but NOT with the subsequent definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double derivative2(double (fun), double step, double x);
```

And

```
double derivative2(double fun(double), double step, double x)
```

Are different things. In the first declaration `fun` is `double`, and in the second `fun` is `double(*)(double)` (a pointer to a function).

Because this function calculates a derivative at a point, the right declaration is the one with the function pointer.

Fix:

```
double derivative2(double fun(double), double step, double x); // 'fun' is a function pointer.

// ...

cout << derivative2(fun, h, x) << endl; // Pass fun as a function pointer.
```